# Problem in transmitting Stereo Camera footage

Tags: video-transmitters, osd

I'm working on a Surveillance drone for underground mining and after assembling drone, I decided to add a companion computer NVIDIA Jetson Nano and a Stereo Depth Camera (Intel realsense D435i stereo depth camera) for 3D mapping using RTAB-MAP (Real Time Appearance Based Mapping) using ROS(Robotic Operating System).

The mapped environment will be visualize in rviz in ROS but for this both Jetson nano as well as ground based control station should be connected to same wifi which is not possible as it will fly in remote areas, indoors, underground mines.

So, Is there any way in which I can get mapped environment and RGB camera footage from D435i to a FPV display screen or any other OSD.